# Javascript for loop that yields the object, not the object index

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a short hand notation for iterating through a javascript array that yields the actual object, instead of the index of the object?

For example:

```
var dataset = ['a','b','c']

for (item in dataset){
    console.log(item);

}
```

I want to log 'a','b','c' -- not 0,1,2.

My reason for not wanting to use dataset[item] is that I have several nested for loops, and the code is getting very verbose.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` -- pretty much every lib offers a flavour of this (e.g. $.each, _.each) or use ES6 `for .. of ..` and transpile

Comment: `for ... in` is for objects, not arrays.

Comment: [Don't use `for in` loops on arrays!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use jQuery (which can blend well with basic JS), it's as simple as this:

```
var dataset = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$(dataset).each(function (i, o) {
    console.log(o);
});
```

What this does, essentially, is performs a foreach loop on `dataset`, treating it like an array containing objects. The index is stored in `i` and a non-jQuery object is stored in `o`. You can use `$(o)` to get the jQuery version of this object.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this can be accomplished using the forEach loop:

```
dataset.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Yep, its going to be sweet when we can do `for (x of dataset) {console.log(x)}`